# switch between forms on ironpython studio

Tags: ironpython, ironpython-studio

I'm new to IronPython, currently using ironpython studio, usually I like to program with Visual Basic or Delphi. My problem is that I don't know how to switch between forms by clicking a button, on Delphi you normaly write this code from a button on "form1":

```
procedure TMain.buttonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    form2.show;
end;
```

in VB you usually write almost the same thing, I'd like to know how to do this in Ironpython studio, I'd be grateful if somebody could help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to add a handler to the button's click event (like you would in C# and not like in VB) and show the other form.  Refer to a C# tutorial for reference, it will be very similar in IronPython.  Or better yet, try to learn about the differences between C#, IronPython, and VB and Delphi.

The button's Click event takes two parameters.  As long as the function takes two parameters (not including the implicit `self`), you're set.

e.g.,

```python
class MyForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        # create a form with a button
        button = Button()
        button.Text = 'Click Me'
        self.Controls.Add(button)

        # register the _button_click() method to the button's Click event
        button.Click += self._button_Click

    def _button_Click(self, sender, e):
        # do what you want to do
        Form2().Show() # create an instance of `Form2` and show it
```